# Spring Boot + DynamoDB Local with Docker: Connect to localhost:8000 failed

Tags: java, spring, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I built a Spring Boot REST API that queries DynamoDB, and I would like to configure one or two Docker containers that run as microservices: one that runs DynamoDB locally and another that runs the REST API. I have a container configured for the Spring Boot REST API, but when I make calls to the API, it cannot query the local DynamoDB even though DynamoDB is running on localhost:8000. The error I get is:

`Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Despite getting that message, I can access DynamoDB via localhost using my browser. It's as if the Docker container will not allow the API to access localhost:8000 even though the API container is running at localhost:8080.

How should I configure my container(s) so that each runs as a separate microservice? Has anyone seen a similar issue before?

Answer (score 1):

**localhost** inside a container doesn't point to real machine host. Literally when you use **localhost** inside any docker container it will be pointing to the container itself.

Docker provides two ways of handling this sitution:

**Links.** This is deprecated way and [should be avoided](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) in new projects.

**Networks.** Docker can establish a network where you can access your containers by DNS names (container ID, or container name).

Create a network in a [way described here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/), replace `localhost` by the name of DB container and you'll be ready to go.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I start the DynamoDB service locally using one container, add it to a network, and then start the REST API and it to the same network. But I still get the same error as above.

Comment: Did you change the connection url in the spring boot container?

Answer (score 0):

Per default the containers are pretty isolated and runnning within separate networks. You have to link DinamoDB container into Spring Boot container using - - link setting:

https://deis.com/blog/2016/connecting-docker-containers-1/

Comment: Is this any different -- or better or worse -- than configuring a Docker service comprised of multiple containers?