# Inside Docker container NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8002

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm building up a nodejs app which is running in the docker container and getting following error

> NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000"

And If I tried with **dynamodb-local:8000** then it will give me following error

> NetworkingError: write EPROTO
>   140494555330368:error:1408F10B:SSLroutines:ssl3_get_record:wrong
>   version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:

I am using the following **docker-compose.yml**

```
        version: "3"

        services:
        node_app:
            build: .
            container_name: 'node_app'
            restart: 'always'
            command: 'npm run start:local'
            ports:
            - "3146:3146"
            links:
            - dynamodb-local
        dynamodb-local:
            container_name: 'dynamodb-local'
            build: dynamodb-local/
            restart: 'always'
            ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

Node js docker configuration as follows, **node_app**

```
        FROM node:latest

        RUN mkdir -p /app/node_app

        WORKDIR /app/node_app


        # Install app dependencies
        COPY package.json /app/node_app
        #RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install
        RUN npm install


        # Bundle app source
        COPY . /app/node_app

        # Build the built version
        EXPOSE 3146
        #RUN npm run dev

        CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Dynamo DB local docker configuration as follows, **dynamodb-local**

```
        #
        # Dockerfile for DynamoDB Local
        #
        # https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/
        #
        FROM openjdk:7-jre

        RUN mkdir -p /var/dynamodb_local
        RUN mkdir -p /var/dynamodb_picstgraph

        # Create working space
        WORKDIR /var/dynamodb_picstgraph

        # Default port for DynamoDB Local
        EXPOSE 8000

        # Get the package from Amazon
        RUN wget -O /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz && \
            tar xfz /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest && \
            rm -f /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest

        # Default command for image
        ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-Djava.library.path=.", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-sharedDb", "-dbPath", "/var/dynamodb_local"]
        CMD ["-port", "8000"]

        # Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
        VOLUME ["/var/dynamodb_local", "/var/dynamodb_nodeapp"]
```

But when I tried to connect outside docker container to local dynamodb and it will work perfectly.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Inside the docker container, the DB will be available with the host `dynamodb-local:8000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot + DynamoDB Local with Docker: Connect to localhost:8000 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260831/spring-boot-dynamodb-local-with-docker-connect-to-localhost8000-failed)

Comment: @DavidMaze I was tried that one as well but not able to resolve my issue

Comment: @RodrigoBrito Yes I tried but its giving me NetworkingError issue

Comment: You can enter in the node container with `docker exec` and use the telnet to test the port connection: eg: `telnet dynamodb-local 8000` and `telnet lolcahost 8000`, if it works the problem is in your database instalation.

Comment: @RodrigoBrito yes its working for  dynamodb-local 8000,

Comment: Nice, then the container have comunication, the second erro seems like a SSL error, are you using any certificate our HTTPS address to connect it?

Comment: @RodrigoBrito no i am not using any ssl

Comment: @RodrigoBrito issue get resolved thanks for your help, its because of ssl for another application on same port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the docker container, the DB will be available with the host `dynamodb-local:8000`.

It might be an SSL issue, please check your apache configuration if you have used the port for other application.

For that case, you can use link dynamo on another port as follows,

```
    #
    # Dockerfile for DynamoDB Local
    #
    # https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/
    #
    FROM openjdk:7-jre

    RUN mkdir -p /var/dynamodb_local
    RUN mkdir -p /var/dynamodb_picstgraph

    # Create working space
    WORKDIR /var/dynamodb_picstgraph

    # Default port for DynamoDB Local
    EXPOSE 8004

    # Get the package from Amazon
    RUN wget -O /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz && \
        tar xfz /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest && \
        rm -f /tmp/dynamodb_local_latest

    # Default command for image
    ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-Djava.library.path=.", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-sharedDb", "-dbPath", "/var/dynamodb_local"]
    CMD ["-port", "8004"]

    # Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
    VOLUME ["/var/dynamodb_local", "/var/dynamodb_nodeapp"]
```

Now in your docker container, the DB will be available with the host `dynamodb-local:8004`.